# Laravel 5.1 /phpunit - Sending headers with get/post calls

Tags: phpunit, laravel-5.1

I am looking for a solution to embed jwt token as header in the get/post requests I sent to the server in my phpunit tests. 
Is there any option to add header to the GET/POST calls? I am currently using following method to send a GET request to the server.

> content = $this->get('users/logout')->response->getContent();

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix the header with `HTTP_`. As Example:

```
$server = ['HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest'];
$this->call('get', '/users/logout', [], [], $server);
```

Alternative syntax::

```
$this->client->setServerParameter('HTTP_X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
$this->call('get', '/users/logout');
```

Hope this help